# Simple resistance based water sensor works in stagnant water but blows out in running water, under faucet

Tags: transistors, mosfet, digital-logic, resistors, sensor

[image]

The circuit is intended to flash an LED every 7 seconds when
there is no water and to flash it very rapidly (time period less than 1 second) when it "senses" water. It all worked well when tested with stagnant water in a plastic mug. But however keeping the probes under running water from a faucet doesn't change the frequency of the LED and moreover damages the Mosfet which makes it not work with even stagnant water in the same mug anymore. I swapped the mosfet with CD4069 ( CMOS Hex inverter ic) and it works fine with stagnant as well as running water. What could be causing the problem. The water comes from an overhead tank and it doesn't carry any stray voltage.

Comment: Have you ever heard of a kelvin generator?

Comment: Have you tried it with a more "solid" stream of water? Domestic water faucets have aerators that break up the stream of water and introduce air, so it is likely the circuit is not getting a continuous signal.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I just looked it up and feels like it could be the culprit. But I am a bit skeptical about the required spark gap forming naturally given that chances for that happening is fairly low.

Comment: @Austin Yes, I checked that while troubleshooting and that wasn't it. Even if it was that, it shouldn't blow out the mosfet and like I said it works fine with the inverter ic.

Comment: @user20962: the "spark gap" is between your gate and source of the FET.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I haven't. But looks like a cool weekend project :)

Comment: @PlasmaHH If that is the case then why would it work perfectly with the NOT GATE in the inverter ic ?

Comment: @user20962: because different FETs have different levels of natural and/or built in protection

Comment: Oh! I see. What would be the best way to add such a protection to the mosfet I have to overcome this problem?

Comment: I would have thought that the 470k pullup resistor would have been adequate to drain off any static charge, but I guess not. Try putting a diode in parallel with it, and maybe another one to ground, to clamp the gate voltage to both supply rails. That's the kind of protection that the inverter has built into it.

Comment: @DaveTweed Yes, I did see shottcky diodes used in a similar arrangement in the block diagram of CD4069. I will try it out with 2N7000. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your transistor gate is being blown by static electricity generated in the flowing water stream. The 4069 does not blow out because it has protection circuity on its inputs while the gate of your transistor is a little "exposed". You can add protection circuitry as follows. Series resistor from input to mosfet gate bigger is safer but will reduce sensitivity you need to decide the balance here start around 1k. One diode cathode to supply+ anode to gate. One diode cathode to gate anode to supply-. These are small diodes they will carry very little power and are normally reverse biased.